# fuse filesystem can not change the value of struct stat *stbuf in getattr function?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fuse, stat

**Question Solved!**
Thanks to @basile-starynkevitch , I find out that the `struct stat` is not at the same size in different files!

In `<sys/stat.h>`, `sizeof(struct stat)` is 88bytes, but with fuse's lib(I guess that due to `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag), this is 96bytes.

So when I add fuse lib to my remote server(add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 /usr/local/lib/libfuse.so /usr/local/lib/libulockmgr.so` flag to gcc), then my program runs correctly!

Thanks to your help!

---

I am doing some projects on fuse, and it got me crazy.

I send struct stat *stbuf 's data from a remote server, and the data is correct in both server and client, but when I use memcpy to duplicate the data into stbuf, it seems that nothing copied. I also try to use read(socked,stbuf,sizeof(struct stat)); directly, but that does not work too.

here is the codes...(if there is no such file, the remote server save -ENOENT in st_ino)

```
    static int rof_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)

        {

    int res = 0;
    struct cmd sndcmd;
    struct stat buf;

    memset(&sndcmd, 0, sizeof(struct cmd));

    strcpy(sndcmd.cmd, "GETATTR");
    strcpy(sndcmd.str, path);
    memset(stbuf, 0, sizeof(struct stat));
GTTR_AGN:   
    memset(&buf, 0,sizeof(struct stat));
    write(sockfd, &sndcmd, sizeof(struct cmd));
    res=read(sockfd, &buf, sizeof(struct stat));

    if(res!=sizeof(struct stat))
        goto GTTR_AGN;

    memcpy(stbuf,&buf,sizeof(buf));
    if (buf.st_ino==-ENOENT)
        return -ENOENT;
return 0;
        }
```

the data I get from gdb:

```
39      res=read(sockfd, &buf, sizeof(struct stat));
3: (struct stat)stbuf = {st_dev = 694294557525955008, __pad1 = 0, __st_ino = 0, 
  st_mode = 0, st_nlink = 0, st_uid = 0, st_gid = 0, st_rdev = 0, __pad2 = 0, 
  st_size = 0, st_blksize = 0, st_blocks = 0, st_atim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, 
  st_mtim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, st_ctim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, 
  st_ino = 0}
1: buf = {st_dev = 0, __pad1 = 0, __st_ino = 0, st_mode = 0, st_nlink = 0, 
  st_uid = 0, st_gid = 0, st_rdev = 0, __pad2 = 0, st_size = 0, st_blksize = 0, 
  st_blocks = 0, st_atim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, st_mtim = {tv_sec = 0, 
    tv_nsec = 0}, st_ctim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, st_ino = 0}
```

after read(), got data in buf

```
(gdb) s
40      memcpy(stbuf,&buf,sizeof(buf));
3: (struct stat)stbuf = {st_dev = 694294557525955008, __pad1 = 2049, __st_ino = 0, 
  st_mode = 0, st_nlink = 943887, st_uid = 16877, st_gid = 2, 
  st_rdev = 4294967297000, __pad2 = 0, st_size = 0, st_blksize = 4096, 
  st_blocks = 34359742464, st_atim = {tv_sec = 1323833759, tv_nsec = 75415995}, 
  st_mtim = {tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_ctim = {
    tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_ino = 0}
1: buf = {st_dev = 2049, __pad1 = 0, __st_ino = 943887, st_mode = 16877, 
  st_nlink = 2, st_uid = 1000, st_gid = 1000, st_rdev = 0, __pad2 = 0, 
  st_size = 17592186048512, st_blksize = 8, st_blocks = 323909233444133279, 
  st_atim = {tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_mtim = {
    tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_ctim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, 
  st_ino = 0}
(gdb) s
```

copy data to stbuf

```
41      if (stbuf->st_ino==-ENOENT)
3: (struct stat)stbuf = {st_dev = 694294557525955008, __pad1 = 2049, __st_ino = 0, 
  st_mode = 0, st_nlink = 943887, st_uid = 16877, st_gid = 2, 
  st_rdev = 4294967297000, __pad2 = 0, st_size = 0, st_blksize = 4096, 
  st_blocks = 34359742464, st_atim = {tv_sec = 1323833759, tv_nsec = 75415995}, 
  st_mtim = {tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_ctim = {
    tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_ino = 0}
1: buf = {st_dev = 2049, __pad1 = 0, __st_ino = 943887, st_mode = 16877, 
  st_nlink = 2, st_uid = 1000, st_gid = 1000, st_rdev = 0, __pad2 = 0, 
  st_size = 17592186048512, st_blksize = 8, st_blocks = 323909233444133279, 
  st_atim = {tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_mtim = {
    tv_sec = 1323729515, tv_nsec = 6514929}, st_ctim = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}, 
  st_ino = 0}
```

stbuf does not change at all.

Can anyone give me some suggestion about such phenomenon? I've done some work but still not find a solution.

Comment: Thanks to Basile Starynkevitch, I add the check on res.

Comment: The check is wrong. As I explained, you have four cases to handle.

Comment: Try to dump in hex and ascii the `buf`. You might have read something unexpected...

Comment: You should print `*stbuf` under `gdb`

Comment: I find the problem, the thing is I did not add a compile flag to server, so the size of this structure is not same as the one in the client. Thanks your help, that's very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **check the number of read bytes** `res`  in your code.

It can be 0 on end of file, it can be -1 on errors, and it could be less than `sizeof(struct stat)` if all bytes have not being received...

Read (with your eyes and brain) very carefully (and read it again twice) the [man page of read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) syscall.

Comment: I do not check that, I just want to know if I get the data correctly, there is no check statement on that in my code right? I add this because I want to display that while debugging. Is that influence the result? I just add a value here...

Comment: You should check the value of `res`.... there are several cases to handle: `res<0` (an error), `res==0` (end of file is reached), `res<sizeof(struct stat)` (partial read), or `res==sizeof(struct stat)` (read fully completed). You could also consider switching to a `FILE*` and use `fread`

Comment: Got that,thanks. Another question, could you please see the gdb output, why I get the data correctly in buf but can not copy that to pointer stbuf?

Comment: could you see the gdb output please? The thing is that I got the data I want in buf... but can not save that to pointer stbuf (`res==sizeof(struct stat)`)

Comment: Did you check in your code that `(res==sizeof(struct stat))` ? I don't see any tests on `res` and you have to handle all the four cases I am mentioning.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add the codes hope I could solve that. The thing I mentioned above is that I use gdb to debug the program, and see the res equals to `sizeof(struct stat)` in gdb.